# A process using CUDA gets stuck, then all others get stuck as well - what do I do?

Tags: drivers, kill, proprietary-drivers, hang, cuda

I’m writing some program using CUDA CUDA 12.1, running on a Linux system (Devuan Daedalus, kernel version 6.1.27).

For some reason (which may be a bug of mine, although I kind of doubt it) - the process gets stuck at some point. Sending it SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGKILL has no effect. The details of what this process does shouldn’t really matter, but - it doesn’t do file I/O, it doesn’t use the network, it doesn’t use any other peripherals - it just uses CUDA APIs (specifically, execution graphs), does some computation in-memory, and prints messages to its standard output.

So, first part of the question question: How can I kill such a process (other than by rebooting the machine)?

Now, after this process gets stuck - any process using CUDA APIs seems to also get stuck, (almost) immediately when starting to run.

Thus, a second part of the question: Can I avoid other processes getting stuck as well?

Comment: … nvidia-grade libraries.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Fair observation; but - what about the surrounding systems? Doesn't Linux, plus the userland, have any prophylactic measures against NVIDIA-grade libraries?

Comment: not really, since a) nvidia supplies an equivalently reliable kernel module as well, which thus runs in Ring 0 (or equivalent if this isn't x86), i.e. at kernel privileges and can do anything, and b) in the end, CUDA and the Nvidia kernel driver it talks to are sharing one resource – graphics cards, their DMA engines and so forth. If that access arbitration, or the hardware (or the software running independently from what your CPU does on the GPU) gets confused, no remedies can exist. The shared resource "graphics card" becomes unresponsive. (good library design **could** gracefully fail…)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: But the issue (at least for the first part of the question) is not arbitration - it's aborting a process. Don't kernel modules have a "lever" the kernel can pull when it wants to kill a process that's in the middle of using them?

Comment: no, not that I'm aware of; system calls could fail (again, and your user land library could gracefully deal with that), but it's not usual that this crashes a process itself – things like segmentation faults or unhandled signals do. Also, it looks like the module just locks up, so that it's the problem itself, and not able to pull any levers.